# Loading bitmap in background with AsyncTask

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

Hello Devs i'm new here and i really wants a help or advice i created music app and i've songs in list view with album artWork but it is loading very slow i want to use asyncTask for loading bitmaps Thanks for any Help.....

here is my code

```
public class SongFragment extends Fragment {


private Context context;
private SongsAdapter songAdt;
private ListView songView;
private ArrayList<Songs> songsList;
//Binder
private boolean musicBound = false;
//Service
private MusicService musicSrv;
private Intent playIntent;
//activity and playback pause flags
private boolean playbackPaused = false;
//connect to the service
private ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MusicService.MusicBinder binder = (com.example.android.materialmusic.MusicService.MusicBinder) service;
        //get service
        musicSrv = binder.getService();
        //pass list
        musicSrv.setList(songsList);
        musicBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        musicBound = false;
    }
};

public SongFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_song, container, false);

    songView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.songs);
    //instantiate list
    songsList = new ArrayList<>();
    //get songs from device
    getSongList();
    //sort alphabetically by title
    Collections.sort(songsList, new Comparator<Songs>() {
        public int compare(Songs a, Songs b) {
            return a.getTitle().compareTo(b.getTitle());
        }
    });

    //create and set adapter
    songAdt = new SongsAdapter(getActivity(), songsList);
    songView.setAdapter(songAdt);

    songView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            musicSrv.setSong(Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString()));
            musicSrv.playSong();
            if (playbackPaused) {
                playbackPaused = false;
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

//start and bind the service when the activity starts
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (playIntent == null) {
        playIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), MusicService.class);
        this.getActivity().bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        this.getActivity().startService(playIntent);
    }
}

//method to retrieve song_item info from device
public void getSongList() {
    //query external audio
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

    if (musicCursor != null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int albumColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow
                (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);

            long thisAlbum = musicCursor.getLong(albumColumn);
            Uri sArtworkUri = Uri
                    .parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
            Uri albumArtUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, thisAlbum);

            Bitmap artWork = null;
            try {
                artWork = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                        musicResolver, albumArtUri);
                artWork = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(artWork, 150, 150, true);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
                artWork = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.no_cover);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            songsList.add(new Songs(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, artWork));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}

private class LoadingBitmap extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return bitmap;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Don't use AsyncTask use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) if you are loading from a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found best method to get album art

```
        Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(getAlbumArtUri(song.getArtWork()))
            .placeholder(R.drawable.no_cover)
            .override(120,120)
            .into(holder.albumArt);

private static Uri getAlbumArtUri(long albumId) {
  return ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart"), albumId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for your purpose, it offers all the tools you currently need, such as fetching the Image and also resizing it for instance and caching.

Best is that you read it for yourself, otherwise I would need to implement entire solution.

Comment: thanks for you answer,  i wanna ask that we dont need to use AsyncTask in glide library

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) like this in your code:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
Glide.with(this).load("your image url").into(imageView);
```

Its easy and convenient to use and will help perform better in your app.

Comment: how to i add glide library in my fragment activity

Comment: Use the above mentioned code or there is a demo available with the library. You can share your code with me here and I can help you with that.

Comment: i use this code in my adapter. Glide.with(contrxt).load(songs.getArtWork).asBitmap().into(imageView).  nothin is showing in the image field

Comment: Just use this code and make sure the link for image is working and you have given permission for Internet in manifest file. Glide.with(context).load("your image url").into(holder.imageView);

Comment: i used this but it didn't retrieveing image from ALBUM_ID

Comment: Please check your URL for image as I am using the same code and it is working fine for me.